# Why Doesn't This Ruby Case Block Evaluate to True?

Tags: ruby

I'm learning case statements for Ruby, and thought this would work, but I am always hitting the else statement. I can never get the input to evaluate as 'true' even when I am passing the input as either 'Cat' or 'Dog'. I did verify that the input type is "String" so I am confused why when I enter 'Cat', when prompted by the gets statement, 'Cat' and 'Cat' in the case block are not setting animal_sound to 'meow'

```
puts "Give me an animal:"
animal = gets

animal_sound = case animal
  when 'Cat' then 'meow'
  when 'Dog' then 'woof'
  else "I don't know that one, so moooo"
end

puts animal_sound
```

Comment: You need to remove the newline stored with `gets`, right now it must be something like "Cat\n", "Dog\n", etc, that's why it's never equal to "Cat", "Dog".

Comment: Ahhh, perfect. Changing `case animal` to `case animal.chomp` worked, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Sebastian Palma pointed out that the `\n` that `gets` adds was causing this to evaluate to false.

Changing `case animal` to `case animal.chomp` fixed the problem.

Comment: I'd use `animal = gets.comp` or `animal = gets(chomp: true)` (in Ruby 2.4 or above)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other input, which is quite correct, you may wish to use regular expressions rather than strings. This makes it trivial to ignore both whitespace and case.

```
puts "Give me an animal:"
animal = gets

animal_sound = case animal
  when /^ \s* cat \s* $/ix then 'meow'
  when /^ \s* dog \s* $/ix then 'woof'
  else "I don't know that one, so moooo"
end

puts animal_sound
```

Comment: This seems more complex than just chomping and trimming.

Comment: Much more flexible, though.

Comment: It may be better to add the flexibility when it's needed, especially since the flexibility comes with a significant cost in readability here.  Still, this is a good example to show another way of handling the problem.